# Trouble connecting network while installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, timeout

Am a total novice with Ubuntu. I'm trying to install Ubuntu onto an Asus Vivostick that can no longer cope with Windows 10. I'm installing from a USB stick. I cannot install Ubuntu because the network configuration keeps timing out. I would need to connect Wifi, but the device is not detecting it - something it could do with Windows 10.

Comment: what if you try to install without connecting to the network?

Comment: It just keeps searching for a network. It stays stuck at step 4/9. Says applying network config, gets to 66% and then times out. I've tried connecting a USB wifi dongle, but no luck...

Comment: during the install there is an option "download updates during install" make sure it is NOT checked and then try shutting off wifi from network menu

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  for the suggestions. I did some other reading and checking around - it seems that Ubuntu 14.05 is  the most stable and easiest version to install. I  have installed it and it is working fine. Thanks.